# Caret re-sampling methods

Tags: r, resampling, caret

I am using the library `caret` in R to test various modelling procedures.

The `trainControl` object allows one to specify a re-sampling method. The methods are described in the [documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/caret/vignettes/caretTrain.pdf) section 2.3 and include: `boot`, `boot632`, `cv`, `LOOCV`, `LGOCV`, `repeatedcv` and `oob`. Although some of these are easy to infer, not all of these methods are clearly defined.

What are the procedures corresponding to these resampling methods?

Comment: documentation link is broken. Use [this](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/caret/vignettes/caret.pdf) instead.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Ok, here is my try:

- boot - bootstrap
- boot632 -- [0.632 bootstrap](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/01621459.1983.10477973)
- cv -- cross-validation, probably this refers to [K-fold cross-validation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics)#K-fold_cross-validation).
- LOOCV -- leave-one-out cross validation, also known as jacknife.
- LGOCV -- leave-group-out cross validation, variant of LOOCV for hierarchical data.
- repeatedcv -- is probably [repeated random sub-sampling validation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics)#Repeated_random_sub-sampling_validation), i.e division to train and test data is done in random way.
- oob -- refers to out-of-bag estimation [proposed by Breiman](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=breiman%20out%20of%20bag%20estimation&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCUQFjAB&url=http://ftp.stat.berkeley.edu/pub/users/breiman/OOBestimation.ps&ei=zQupTpSgNsSb8gPC2cSKDA&usg=AFQjCNH87s9c2ppttu4jgBg7o2NOzdkcIA), which further is related to [bootstrap aggregating](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_aggregating). (The file in the link is not a ps file, but a ps.Z file, rename it and then try opening.)

Comment: I believe that LGOCV is random splitting between a training set and validation set, repeated n times. So, instead of the ordinary case of splitting data between train and hold-out (build model on train and validate on hold out) once, this process is repeated many times.

Comment: I also believe that repeatedCV is k-fold cross validation, done multiple times.

Comment: Hard to believe this isn't documented somewhere.

Answer (score 5):

The `repeatedcv` is repeated 10–fold cross–validation for sure, according to Max Kuhn's presentation. The default resampling scheme is the bootstrap.

A good file that you can look about resampling methods is *Predictive Modeling with R and the caret Package* ([pdf](http://www.edii.uclm.es/~useR-2013/Tutorials/kuhn/user_caret_2up.pdf)). Max presented this in "useR! 2013".