# In caret what is the real difference between cv and repeatedcv?

Tags: r, machine-learning, caret

This is similar to question [Caret re-sampling methods](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/17602/caret-re-sampling-methods), although that really never answered this part of the question in an agreed upon way.

caret's train function offers `cv` and `repeatedcv`.  What is the difference in say doing:

```
MyTrainControl=trainControl(
    method = "cv",
    number=5,
    repeats=5
)
```

vs

```
MyTrainControl=trainControl(
   method = "repeatedcv",
   number=5,
   repeats=5
)
```

I understand `cv` breaks the set into k-folds (parameter `number`), and then starts over and runs it parameters `repeats` number of times.

The only thing I could think of is that maybe regular `cv` with `repeats` uses the same exact indexes for the folds each time? essentially running the `cv` on the same exact folds each time, vs perhaps `repeatedcv` selects new folds each times?

Can someone clarify?

Comment: I wonder there are some more methods as well.. need some basic level understanding of each, is there anywhere I could find that? thanks.

Comment: In create multi fold, code iterates over multiple times (given by repeats in train `Control()` syntax in R) for each of the k cross fold (given by number). In cross fold, while using CV, it is a one time process on each of the fold (set by using numbers in train `control()`).

Answer (score 33):

According to the [caret manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/caret/)(see "reference manual"), the parameter `repeats` only applies when the `method` is set to `repeatedcv`, so no repetition is performed when the `method` is set to `cv`. So the difference between both methods is indeed that `repeatedcv` repeats and `cv` does not.

---

Aside: Repeating a crossvalidation with exactly the same splitting will yield exactly the same result for every repetition (assuming that the model is trained in a deterministic manner), which is not only inefficient, but also dangerous when it comes to comparing the validation results for different model algorithms in a statistical manner. So be aware of this if you ever have to program a validation yourself.

Comment: broken link, now it's https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/caret/vignettes/caret.pdf

also, it's on page 4 now.  just search for 'repeatedcv'

Comment: the PDF link is no longer working.  The following URL seems to be the replacement.   https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/caret/vignettes/caret.html

Answer (score 4):

Admittedly, this is a **VERY** old post, but based on the code snippets provided by user3466398, the difference is that repeatedcv does exactly that: it repeatedly performs X-fold cross-validation on the training data, i.e. if you specify 5 repeats of 10-fold cross-validation, it will perform 10-fold cross-validation on the training data 5 times, using a different set of folds for each cross-validation.

The rationale for doing this, I presume, is to allow one to have a more accurate and robust accuracy of the cross-validation testing, i.e. one can report the average CV accuracy.

Comment: But is it nested cross-validation?
How can we use it to tune parameters?

Answer (score 3):

The actual code behind these parameters can be found in the `selectByFilter.R` and `createDataPartition.R` (formerly `createFolds.R`) source files in the `caret/R/' folder of the package.

See these files for e.g. [here](https://github.com/topepo/caret/blob/8f15fdb2c328257f22382ac1aadb26622f14fb64/pkg/caret/R/selectByFilter.R#L177) and [here](https://github.com/topepo/caret/blob/8f15fdb2c328257f22382ac1aadb26622f14fb64/pkg/caret/R/createDataPartition.R#L227) (beware these permalinks may eventually point to older version of the code).  For convenience the relevant snippets (as of version 6.0-78 c. Nov 2017) are show below

In selectByFilter.R c. line 157

```
sbf <- function (x, ...) UseMethod("sbf")
... 

"sbf.default" <-
  function(x, y,
           sbfControl = sbfControl(), ...)
  {
    ...

    if(is.null(sbfControl$index)) sbfControl$index <- switch(
      tolower(sbfControl$method),
      cv = createFolds(y, sbfControl$number, returnTrain = TRUE),
      repeatedcv = createMultiFolds(y, sbfControl$number, sbfControl$repeats),
      loocv = createFolds(y, length(y), returnTrain = TRUE),
      boot =, boot632 = createResample(y, sbfControl$number),
      test = createDataPartition(y, 1, sbfControl$p),
      lgocv = createDataPartition(y, sbfControl$number, sbfControl$p))
...
```

In createDataPartition.R c. line 227

```
createMultiFolds <- function(y, k = 10, times = 5) {
  if(class(y)[1] == "Surv") y <- y[,"time"]
  prettyNums <- paste("Rep", gsub(" ", "0", format(1:times)), sep = "")
  for(i in 1:times) {
    tmp <- createFolds(y, k = k, list = TRUE, returnTrain = TRUE)
    names(tmp) <- paste("Fold",
                        gsub(" ", "0", format(seq(along = tmp))),
                        ".",
                        prettyNums[i],
                        sep = "")
    out <- if(i == 1) tmp else c(out, tmp)

  }
  out
}
```

Comment: take a look at their functions....https://github.com/tonglu/caret/blob/master/pkg/caret/R/createFolds.R#L63

Comment: Could you please give more context in your answer? Links are good, but we try to avoid answers that won't stand on their own -- links can disappear.